# iframe content with style in head with hex color code not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am generating iframe using javascript with dynamic html.
My dynamic html looks like-

```
<head>
<style>
...
.bar {background-color: #EB593C;}
...
</style>
</head>
```

Then iframe contents all code till .bar {background-color: 
after color code html/css is not included in iframes contents.

If I replace hex color code with rgb or text color name then that is working fine.

But as I said html is dynamic so I cant replace all the hex color codes to to rgb or text.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
//var html = '<style>body {background-color: #EB593C;}</style><body>Foo</body>'; // not working
var html = '<style>body {background-color: red;}</style><body>Foo</body>'; // working
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kbyqpej/1/)

Comment: Seems to be issue related to Mozilla Firefox browser. Works fine with Chrome browser.

Comment: @MagikTejas thanks for reply.
Ohh I see. Still waiting for solution...