# Cannot use CSS '#' symbol in iframe

Tags: css, iframe

> Scenario

I have created a simple iframe which i am dynamically generating from user provided HTML and CSS.

> JSfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jaup3769/1/

> Problem

Whenever I use the '#' symbol, CSS parsing is stopped beyond that point.

```
p#para1{

}
```

won't parse beyond `p#`

Similarly,

```
p{
 color: green;
 background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

won't parse beyond `background-color: #`

What might be the issue?

Comment: fiddle works fine for me in chrome?

Comment: The question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437019/iframe-content-with-style-in-head-with-hex-color-code-not-working states the it is a mozilla-only issue, which seems to be true. So, what possible workaround is suggested instead the approach used in fiddle?

Comment: The # is being treated as a fragment identifier. It's not clear which browser is behaving correctly, but either way, that's the reason why. The workaround is supposed to be to just use the srcdoc attribute like a normal person instead of trying to encode the HTML as a data URI with the src attribute, but Microsoft Edge doesn't support the srcdoc attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`. From the MDN article:

> `encodeURIComponent` differ from `encodeURI` in that it encode reserved
>   characters and Number sign #

I think it even makes more sense to use it in the code you provided, since you are not encoding the whole URI, the `data:whatever/charset:…` part is already there…

- [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
- [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ca3ne6r/)
- [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/should-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls)